# which standard controller should be used to override Person account "New" and "Edit" Page using VF Page?

Tags: visualforce, person-accounts, standardcontroller, button-overrides

I am overriding person account standard Page with VF page. If I use standard controller as "**Account**" I am unable to get Picklist field values from "Person Account", If I use "**Contact**" as a Standard Controller I will get all picklist field value but can not Override "New" button in standard "Account" object.

This is my visualforce Page

```
<apex:page standardController="Contact" extensions="Account_ext" tabStyle="account" sidebar="false" >
<apex:form >
 <apex:pageBlock title="Person Contact Edit">
   <apex:pageBlockButtons >
       <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!save}"/>
       <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" action="{!cancel}"/>
       <apex:commandButton value="Save & New" />

   </apex:pageBlockButtons>
    <Apex:pageBlockSection >

     <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
<apex:outputlabel value="First Name"/>
<apex:outputpanel >
    <apex:outputfield value="{!Contact.Salutation}" />
    &nbsp;
    <apex:outputfield value="{!Contact.FirstName}" />
</apex:outputpanel>
   </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>   


       <apex:inputField value="{!Contact.lastname}"/>        
        <Apex:inputField value="{!Contact.Lead_Source__c}" />
        <apex:inputField value="{!Contact.Enquiry_Budget__c}"/>
         <apex:inputField value="{!Contact.Enquiry_check__c}"/>
        <apex:inputField value="{!Contact.Enquiry_Flat_Type__c}"/>
         <apex:inputField value="{!Contact.Enquiry_Locality_Preference__c}"/>
         <apex:inputField value="{!Contact.Enquiry_Location__c}"/>
          <apex:inputField value="{!Contact.Enquiry_Name__c}"/>
         <apex:inputField value="{!Contact.Enquiry_Potential_Name__c}"/>
         <apex:inputField value="{!Contact.Enquiry_Property_Type_Preference__c}"/>
         <apex:inputField value="{!Contact.Enquiry_Type_Of_Purchase__c}"/>
         <apex:inputField value="{!Contact.Lead_Source__c}"/>
       <apex:inputField value="{!Contact.Mailing_City__c}"/>
     <apex:inputField value="{!Contact.Mailing_Country__c}"/>
       <apex:inputField value="{!Contact.Mailing_State_Province__c}"/>
       <apex:inputField value="{!Contact.Mailing_Street__c}"/>
       <apex:inputField value="{!Contact.Mailing_Zip_Postal_Code__c}"/>  
       <apex:inputField value="{!Contact.Opportunities__c}"/>


      <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
       <apex:outputLabel >Project</apex:outputLabel>
                    <apex:selectList multiselect="false" size="1" value="{!Contact.Project__c}">
                        <apex:selectOptions value="{!prj}" />
                    </apex:selectList>   
       </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>  
    </Apex:pageBlockSection>

 </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>

</apex:page>
```

This is my Controller as of Now still work is on.....

```
public class Account_ext {

    public Account_ext(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {

    }
     public string prj;

    List<selectOption> options = new List<selectOption>();
    public List<selectOption> getprj() {
        for(project__c acc : [select Id,name from project__c])
        {
            options.add(new selectOption(acc.name,acc.name));
        }
        return options;
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you have an example of where it is not working using the Account standard controller? Your current code sample only shows using the Contacts standard controller.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to setup a dispatcher page that you will use in your New override. It should inspect the record type and then redirect to the right page. See this blog post on how to do that: http://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2008/11/14/redirecting-users-to-different-visualforce-pages/

Comment: what about the standard controller whether it should be "Account" Or "Contact". If it is contact it saves record in contact, if account it won't fetch field values.

Comment: I don't have too much experience with coding around person accounts, but I was thinking your dispatcher would use Account and then redirect the user to the page you posted in the question. Is that one not working?

Comment: i am working on that, i will let you know once done